# Characterize the positive integers n for which $\phi(n) | n$ holds

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Characterize the positive integers n for which $\phi(n) | n$ holds

Tried writing $\phi(n)$ as $n\prod_{p|n}$$(1-$${1}\over {p}$$)$, but then n gets removed from both sides of the equation when you write $n$=$nq\prod_{p|n}$$(1-$${1}\over {p}$$)$

Answer (score 2):

From your finding, $$q=\prod_{p\mid n}\frac1{1-\frac1p} =\prod_{p\mid n}\frac p{p-1}$$
must be an integer. Note that only $p=2$ gives you an even numerator, all others give you an even denominator. Hence if there are two odd primes dividing $n$, you cannot obtain an integer. Hence $n$ is divisible by at most one odd prime $p$ (but possibly also by $2$). So either $n=2^a$ or $n=p^b$ or $n=2^ap^b$; compute $\phi(n)$ for all cases.